# Add "1" to the start and end of an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to write a function to add a "1" to the start and end of an array.

Code I tried:

```
var addTwo = function(array) { 

    var myArray = array;
    var arrayLength;

    arrayLength = array.unshift(1);
    arrayLength = array.push(1);
    return myArray;
};
```

Comment: This is not java!

Comment: Are you sure this is Java, not Java Script?

Comment: That's great, I love SO!

Comment: *"Code I tried"* And? What happened when you tried it? What issues are you running into?

Comment: Note: The `myArray;` at the end of the function doesn't do anything. In particular, it doesn't return the value of `myArray`. If you want to return the array reference, do `return myArray;`

Comment: I'm trying to do a simple JavaScript Tutorial online, and having trouble passing this checkpoint.  IT runs a test of this function addTwo which inputs an array: ["apple", "orange", "banana"] and checks for the function to return [1,"apple","orange","banana",1]

Comment: @JasonJohnson: Then the issue was that you're not returning anything from the function. I've posted an answer showing how to do that.

Comment: You could accept one of the provided answers

Answer (score 1):

The only issues I can see with your function are that you're doing

```
myArray;
```

at the end, which doesn't do anything useful, you're not using the `arrayLength` variable for anything, and you don't need the `myArray` variable. The `unshift` and `push` are fine.

So perhaps:

```
var addTwo = function(array) { 
    array.unshift(1);
    array.push(1);
    return array;
};
```

The only reason you need to return `array` is if the caller doesn't already have a handy reference to it.

Usage examples:

```
var a = ["apple","orange","banana"];
addTwo(a);
console.log(a); // [1, "apple", "orange", "banana", 1]
```

```js
var addTwo = function(array) {
  array.unshift(1);
  array.push(1);
  return array;
};

var a = ["apple","orange","banana"];
addTwo(a);
console.log(a); // [1, "apple", "orange", "banana", 1]
```

and

```
var a = addTwo(["apple","orange","banana"]);
console.log(a); // [1, "apple", "orange", "banana", 1]
```

```js
var addTwo = function(array) {
  array.unshift(1);
  array.push(1);
  return array;
};

var a = addTwo(["apple","orange","banana"]);
console.log(a); // [1, "apple", "orange", "banana", 1]
```

Comment: Thank you i was confused I would like to show you a screenshot to explain why i typed my code the way i did